# centOS Security Center yum install dependencies failing

Tags: linux, centos, dependencies, rpm, yum

I am running a centOS 7 virtual machine and trying to install an RPM package for Security Center 4.7.1. The yum installer fails to find the install packages for the dependencies libexpat and libreadline, however I do have expat and readline installed. I don't understand this because it seems that the Security Center RPM is looking for packages of the wrong names. This link is a screen shot showing the yum install abort, the lack of installed packages required and the packages I do have installed relevant to the problem...
[centOS VM screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnB8a.png)

Any suggestions on how to remedy this without forcing the install and risking non functionality of Security Center?

Comment: don't use screenshots; add the text of your console in your question if possible

Comment: @ChrisMaes Sorry, I would have if it was easier to get console text out of VMWare workstation from a bare-bones OS

Answer (score 0):

The package you are trying to install needs

```
libexpat.so.0
libreadline.so.5
```

but your installation has probably (from what I can see)

```
libexpat.so.2
libreadline.so.6
```

It will be difficult to install this package; I would recommend you to search for a newer SecurityCenter package.

**for experts:**
there is probably a way to work around this; if you can manage to install an older libreadline and libexpat rpm *side by side* with the new ones; but that might be risky because there are probably some conflicts and updates might not run too well...

Comment: Could I uninstall my current versions of readline and expat and then reinstall and specify the version I want in the yum installer?

Comment: yes you could, but probably there are other programs that need them. I wouldn't recommend that...